# Why does scene not being displayed when widget is set as central

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a problem displaying two labels, the label "label" is displayed with no problem ( it has some buttons adjusted Horizontally ) and the second label "label1" is not being displayed ( it contains a scene which has a view , in the scene i have a title and a picture ). This is the code i am trying to use.

```
widget1 = new QWidget;
setCentralWidget(widget1);

label1 = new QLabel(widget1);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(label1);
vue = new QGraphicsView(scene);
label1->move(100,100);

label = new QLabel(widget1);
layout = new QHBoxLayout(label);
label->resize(500,100);
```

It's my first time using QGraphicsScene/View and it is confusing me a little bit.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You're definitly not using all those widgets the right way.
you don't need a label to display a QGraphcisView, neither the QGraphicsScene to be the child of the label.

If you want to display, let's say, a label and a view in the center widget you could write this :

```
//==== Central widget part
QWidget* widget = new QWidget(this);

setCentralWidget(widget);

//==== Graphics part
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphcisScene(this);
QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(widget);

view->setScene(scene);

//==== Label part
QLabel* label = new QLabel(widget);

//==== Layout part
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);

layout.addWidget(label);
layout.addWidget(view);

widget.setLatout(layout);
```

This should show a label and a graphics view in row.

If you allow me a piece of advice : you should understand the parenting system before trying to use the QGraphics module. It's one of the cornerstones of Qt and that what you did wrong here. Starts here for the parenting system : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

and here for the graphics : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html

Hope that helps you.